# "Map" with more than one parameter and iterating without "for"

Tags: python, python-itertools, map-function

1. Have the following line of code, which reads pairs of words from a file, splits them, and returns a tuple, where the first index of each tuple is either the first or second word. 
   For example, a `Bob, Smith` will translate to `[(Bob, Smith)]` and `[(Smith, Bob)]` respectively. I map this to every pair in `g.readlines()`.

   Was wondering if it was at all possible to pass a **second** parameter `flip = True`, into a more general word_flip() function which can be used with map?

   ```
   first_word_is_first = map(first_second_split, g.readlines())

   first_word_is_second = map(second_first_split, g.readlines())
   ```
2. A random question regarding a more functional approach, If I am given a string, and I would like to partition that string based on the attribute of each word (ie. `Alex Smith AGE 35 420`) is there a more functional way approach such a problem besides iterating through `string.split()` and dividing the line into str variables, `name`, `age`, `room_number` or using regex? Is it at all possible to use map, filter, or itertools? Would preferably pass through the string once.

Comment: This is not very idiomatic for Python (and probably will not work well for big input files). Are you porting from another language?

Comment: Please don't ask two questions at once. It is OK to create two questions at once. Your first question would be greatly improved if you provided explicit examples of input and expected output.

Comment: For one, my answer to your first question might be spot on, but my second answer falling short of your needs. Another answer might provide the best solution for your second problem, but misses out on the first altogether. Which one would be your best answer to accept then? How do you expect people to vote?

Comment: Sorry, as you may have noticed, the second question is a bit more open ended than the first, its something I was just wondering about as an aside, I will specify that in the question but you basically nailed my first question so I suppose you get the best answer :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you could use a [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to add additional arguments to your function when using it in a `map()`.

   ```
   from functools import partial
   first_word_is_first = map(partial(word_flip, flip=False), g.readlines())
   first_word_is_second = map(partial(word_flip, flip=True), g.readlines())
   ```

   It'll be easier to use a list comprehension though:

   ```
   first_word_is_first = [word_flip(l, flip=False) for l in g.readlines()]
   first_word_is_second = [word_flip(l, flip=True) for l in g.readlines()]
   ```
2. The way your string is structured (spaces both between fields and inside of the fields) you'll have to use a method like a regex or dedicated function to split out the fields.

Answer (score 0):

for 2:

```
name, surname, n, age, room = 'Alex Smith AGE 35 420'.split()
```

return multiple results from method call.

Comment: Heh, didn't see your answer when I made my comment about two questions... Thanks for proving the point! :-P

Comment: I don't know how my answer proves anything. It is pretty silly :P

Comment: See [my comment to the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931140/python-map-with-more-than-one-parameter-and-iterating-without-for/11931236#comment15890673_11931140) asking him to stick to one question per post.